# With pen and paper, digits that follow the first occurrence of a sequence in pi

Tags: pi, decimal-expansion

Let's suppose that we know where the first occurrence of a sequence of *n* digits appears in the number pi decimal section. For example, the first occurrence of the sequence *26091955* appears in the decimal position 107,607,919.

Is there any way to calculate manually (pen and paper) the decimal digits that would follow? (in the example, it'd be *25916325541684811916*)

Comment: Calculating seems hard.. If i want to figure out pi, i usually just throw frozen hot dogs on the kitchen floor. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: There isn't any such way known currently, in base 10, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [there is a way](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20010.5.shtml) to calculate the N-th digit of $\pi$ (in base 16) independent of the other digits.
So, technically the answer is YES. but it's even better than your question. I don't care about the sequence of digits, you just tell me the position.
The formula is (taken from the link mentioned above)

$$\pi=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}16^{-k} \times\left(\frac{4}{8k+1} - \frac{2}{8k +4} - \frac{1}{8 k +5} - \frac{1}{8k +6}\right).$$

Source: Su, Francis E., et al. "Finding the N-th digit of Pi." Math Fun Facts. http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Ankoganit. I struggled with it for a while.

Comment: You're welcome. :-)

Comment: i vaguely remebered there was a way to calculate the n-th digit, even though i dont really think this question is a valid puzzle (especially since the sequence is comepletly irrelevant), this would be the answer if it was

Comment: The algorithm this gives isn't really doable with pencil and paper, though.

Comment: Where the **first appearance** of particular number string is another story.  See this [**link**](https://www.angio.net/pi/digits.html)